# net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID when using multiple server_name in nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx container to access different services provided by other containers.
i have an app hosted on app-something.domain.com with an ssl certificates all is well but my problem is when i want to add an alias, app.domain.com. the one who did it before me had done something like this

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    listen                  [::]:80;
    server_name             app-something.domain.com app.domain.com;
}

server {
    listen                  443 ssl;
    listen                  [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name             app-something.domain.com app.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate         certificate/path;
    ssl_certificate_key     certificate/key/path;

    location / {
        resolver            ip valid=30s;
        set                 $backend "http://app-url:port";
        proxy_pass          $backend;
    }
}
```

when i do the same, i get an ssl error because app.domain.com uses the certificate of another domain.
the certificate is a multi domain certificate and it has been generated using acme.sh with the following command:

```
acme.sh --home home/path/ -w webroot/path --issue -d app-something.domain.com -d app.domain.com
```

i'd like to understand how to make an alias for the subdomain, the fact that i'm getting different result than people who did it before me by doing the very same thing as them is confusing me.

thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left it aside for a while since not urgent came back to it after a month the cert has been renewed and it runs fine even though deleting the cert and generating a new one did not work